# Galaxy s9+ not charging via USB-C cable and not quick charging at all

Tags: samsung, charging, samsung-galaxy-s-9

I ran into a problem with my Galaxy s9+ recently, it won't charge at all using my [Samsung 25 Watt Wall Charger](https://shop.samsung.ch/en/samsung-pd-25w-wall-charger-black/pid/480903) and also won't charge using my [Aukey 26800mah power bank](https://www.aukey.com/products/26800mah-power-bank-with-2-way-power-delivery-force-plus-series-pb-xd26) when connected via USB-C. It however will charge when I connect my phone to the power bank using a USB-A to USB-C cable. As of right now there is no way I can quick charge my phone, even using a brand new Samsung charger that came in the box will not quick charge my phone, only cable charging.

What chargers I tested:

- [The in the box Samsung charger](https://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/mobile-accessories/phones/adaptive-fast-charging-wall-charger-detachable-microusb-usb-cable-white-ep-ta20jweusta/)

  - This will charge my phone, but only "cable charging", no fast charging
- [Samsung 25 Watt Wall Charger](https://shop.samsung.ch/en/samsung-pd-25w-wall-charger-black/pid/480903)

  - This one won't charge my phone at all
- [Aukey PA-6Y](https://www.aukey.com/products/amp-usb-c-wall-charger-with-power-delivery-3-0-pa-y10)

  - This one charges my phone with quick charge, but only when using the USB-A connector, and won't charge my phone when using the USB-C port
  - This one is also an interesting case, as it has a USB-A and USB-C plug
- [Lenovo 65 Watt laptop charger](https://www.lenovo.com/ch/en/accessories-and-monitors/chargers-and-batteries/chargers/PWR-ADP-BO-Type-C-65W-Adapter/p/4X20M26277)

  - This one won't charge my phone at all

I tested all of these chargers at 2 different physical locations and 2 different sockets at each location so I cannot possibly be a problem with the Socket. I also tested all these chargers with my brothers Galaxy s10+ and each of these chargers charge his phone with quick charging.

But I have also been seeing some very weird behaviour from my phone. For example: I bought the 25 Watt Samsung wall charger brand new and tested it out, it worked perfectly. A day later I wanted to plug in my phone again and it won't charge anymore, just for me to unplug it, turn around the USB-C connector and plug it in and to work again. Once more a day later I wanted to charge my phone again, only for it to not work at all, no matter the USB-C orientation (which shouldn't matter anyways).

I've exhausted every opportunity at my disposal and don't know what could possibly be the problem. I also brought in my phone to my cell carrier (where I have it insured) only for them to say "it quick charges with this charger, I don't see a problem". The only constant I was able to find was that my phone won't charge when using a USB-C to USB-C cable, but will charge (and sometimes quick charge) when using a USB-A to USB-C cable (I tried this on the Aukey charger and the two Samsung chargers back this up)

So my question is this: Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this and how I could fix this?

Comment: Have you enabled quick charging in the settings? According to the Samsung documentation quick charging via cable is disabled by default (because it reduces the battery life time).

Comment: Weird, I never turned it on and just checked that it is in fact turned on. Else the Aukey adapter wouldn't have quick charged my phone